# An interesting maximum area of a triangle problem, but with logarithms

Tags: logarithms, area

[image: Click here for the problem]

I think B $(2/e^2)$ is the answer (multiple choice), but I want to ask you if I solved it correctly (I don't have any book or pdf for answer and for explanation), and here comes the explanation:

Let's first define the graph of the tangent line as $y = mx + b$. First of all, since the value of $m$ is differentiated for $f(t) = -\ln(t)$ for t, therefore
$$a = -\frac{1}{t}$$

And since the graph of the tangent line is always past the point $P(t, -\ln(t))$, we can substitute these values into the graph of the tangent line:
$$
\begin{split}
-\ln(t) &= -\frac{1}{t} \times t + b\\
-\ln(t) &= -1 + b\\
b &= - \ln(t) + 1
\end{split}
$$

Therefore, the graph of the tangent line can be defined as
$$f(x) = -\frac{1}{t}x - \ln(t) + 1$$

Now, to find the area of the triangle, we must know the base length and the height of the triangle. The base length of the triangle is the distance between the points Q and R. The x value of the point Q is equal to t, and to find the x value of the point R, put y=0 to the graph of the tangent line:
$$-\frac{1}{t}x - ln(t) + 1 = 0$$
$$-\frac{1}{t}x = ln(t) - 1$$
$$x = -t(ln(t) - 1)$$
$$x = -tln(t) + t$$
Subtract t from this value, and we get the distance between the points Q and R, which is simultaneously the base length of the triangle, which is -tln(t).

The height of the triangle is -ln(t) since the height of the triangle is the y value of the point P. We use our area of triangle formula to find the area of the triangle, and I will define this A(t).
$$A(t) = \frac{1}{2} \times (-ln(t)) \times (-tln(t)) = \frac{1}{2} t (ln(t))^2$$

We found the formula for the area of the triangle PQR, and to find the maximum value of the area, we are going to find the local maximum of the function A(t). To find the local maximum value, differentiate A(t), and then find the value of the t which makes A'(t) = 0:

$$A'(t) = \frac{1}{2} ((ln(t))^2 + 2ln(t)) = 0$$
$$(ln(t))^2 + 2ln(t) = 0$$
$$ln(t) \times (ln(t) + 2) = 0$$

From here, ln(t) = 0, or ln(t) + 2 = 0. When ln(t) = 0, t is 1, but that doesn't satisfy the condition 0 < t < 1. So t is not 1. But when ln(t) + 2 = 0, ln(t) = -2, and t is e^(-2). Since this value of t satisfy the condition 0 < t < 1 (0 < e^(-2) < 1), t = e^(-2). A(t) is local maximum at t=e^(-2).

The final step: put t = e^(-2) into A(t) and we get:

$$A(e^{-2}) = \frac{1}{2} e^{-2} (ln(e^{-2}))^2 = \frac{1}{2} e^{-2} (-2)^2 = \frac{4}{2} e^{-2} = 2e^{-2} = \frac{2}{e^2}$$

I will be very very happy if someone in this community determines whether the answer to this problem is correct or not.

Comment: Yes it seems correct.

Comment: Your answer is perfectly fine. However, one additional sentence to clarify that $-\ln (t)$ is indeed a positive number would be great because otherwise you would need $|-\ln(t)|$ for calculating the area

Comment: Good solution, you could calculate also find the length of the base by noting that the base length divided by the height is the gradient of the tangent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curve is $y=-\ln x$,
Tangent at (x,y) is given as $$Y-y=\frac{dy}{dx}(X-x) \implies OR=x-y \frac{dx}{dy}=x+xy$$
Then $QR=OR-x=xy$, then area of the triangle PQR is $$A(t)=\frac{1}{2}xy^2=\frac{1}{2}t \ln^2 t \implies A'(t)=\frac{1}{2}\ln^2 t+\ln t=0 \implies t=e^{-2}$$
So $$A_{max}=A(e^{-2})=\frac{2}{e^2}$$

Comment: Ok! The truth is that this problem is an (university entrance) examination problem for South Korean, and this is actually a way to solve this question, but more simple. Thank you for your amazing answer! I appreciate it!

Comment: Thanks, for your appreciation.

Answer (score 1):

Your working is correct but here is how you can simplify your working using slope of the tangent line.

$ \displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx} = - \frac{1}{x}$

If $\angle PRQ = \theta \ $, slope $ \displaystyle m = \tan (\pi-\theta) = - \frac{1}{t} \implies \tan \theta = \frac{1}{t}$

As $PQ = - \ln t, \ QR = - \ln t  \times \cot \theta = - t  \ln t $

So area of the triangle $ \displaystyle A = \frac{1}{2} \ t \ (\ln t)^2$

Now you can differentiate and find $t$ where $A$ is max.

Comment: Wow! This is interesting, but also an easier way to find the formula for the triangle! I appreciate it!

Comment: you are welcome!